# How do I determine whether two vectors have the same direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, coordinate-systems, geometry

Example

E 38 Degrees N
vs 
N 38 Degrees E

I was taught that the angle is indicative of direction so is it useful to just ignore the E and the N components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can describe the vector using angle and magnitude (30 degrees, 10 meters), or you can use the magnitude and a direction.

The way you've written it seems to be a way of saying, 38 degrees east of north and 38 degrees north of east.

These don't mean the same thing: if you look at purely the angles, the "of north" tells you the starting ray, and the "degrees east" tells you how many degrees and on which side of the ray.

The following diagram should help you out.

[image]

Comment: The diagram was super helpful thank you!

Comment: @defaultmandelbrotsetting if you're question's been answered, please accept/green tick the most acceptable answer. This helps people know that it's been solved.

Answer (score 1):

> E 38 Degrees N.

can be interpreted as a vector pointing East which is then rotated $38^\circ$ towards the North and this is not the same as

> N 38 Degrees E.

which can be interpreted as a vector pointing North which is then rotated $38^\circ$ towards the East.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described the vector right. There are two common ways to do it.

You can give the length and angle. Walk 30 feet at an angle of 38 degrees.

You can give East and North components. Walk east 23.64 feet, and then north 18.47 feet.